# Chrome ALT+HOME opens the old Homepage

Tags: google-chrome, keyboard-shortcuts, homepage

I used to have the iGoogle page set as Homepage in Google Chrome.

Now, as the iGoogle service will be retired, I searched for alternatives, [found some](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/28590/12705), and adjusted my Chrome Homepage accordingly.

When I open Chrome it's OK, the new homepage gets shown. 
But when I press <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>HOME</kbd> in a tab, I am taken to iGoogle, although the [Chrome documentation](https://support.google.com/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=157179) says that this keyboard shortcut "*Opens your homepage in your current window*".

Is this a bug or am I missing something?

Comment: [Similar](http://superuser.com/questions/448380/change-the-home-button-in-chrome)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Under Chrome > Settings > Appearance there is a checkbox for "Show Home button". Right under this checkbox is a "New Tab page" label a "Change" link net to it. Click this "Change" to to set you New Tab location.

Comment: I wasn't referring to new tabs, but to the ALT+HOME shortcut that should navigate to the home page _in the current tab_

Comment: I gave it a try and it worked! I thought that the 'On Startup' section was in fact the home page, but I was wrong. Thanks a lot!