# Change the Home button in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome

I have configured Chrome to open on a page other than the google.com. However, whenever I click on the home button it opens up the google.com page. Is there any way in which I can configure the home page and start page to be the same?

Comment: [Similar](http://superuser.com/questions/448363/chrome-althome-opens-the-old-homepage)

Answer (score 1):

Click on the wrench and click "Settings". Click "Settings" on the upper-left, and select "Open a specific page or set of pages", under the "On Startup" section. You can then set the pages that will open when Chrome starts to be the same as your homepage. To set your homepage, select "Show Home button" under "Appearance", and click "Change" to set your homepage.

Answer (score 1):

In the chrome options in the section "Appearance" there is a checkbox "Show Home Button".

Just under that box there is your homepage with a link "Change" next to it, click on this link to change your homepage :-)

Answer (score 1):

Go into Chrome's settings and in the main window, look for the heading labeled **On Startup**.  In there, find the option **Open a Specific Set of Pages**.  This gives you the ability to define one or many pages to open on startup.

Answer (score 0):

Go to settings-> On start up -> Click on specific set of pages-> set URl that you want to open.

Now go to appearance ->click on show Home button -> then Change. Set the same Url in both the cases. Otherwise you will get different pages on startup and on clicking Home.